# Remove value from an array nested in an object also nested in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, data-structures

I have a problem with my code. I currently have some data like the one below;

```
 users: [
    {
      name: 'bolu',
      features: ['Tall'],
    },
    {
      name: 'cam',
      features: ['Bearded', 'Short'],
    },
  ],
};
```

What I am trying to do is delete/remove a single feature - for example if I pass in 'short' into my redux action. I'd like for it (the 'Short' text) to be removed from the features array. I currently have my redux action set up this way:

```
export interface UsersDataState {
  name: string,
  features: Array<string>,
}

export interface UsersState {
  users: UsersDataState[];
}

const initialState: UsersState = {
  users: [],
};

    export const usersSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'users',
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        removeUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
          const removedUsers = state.users.filter((user) => user.features.indexOf(action.payload));
          state.users = removedUsers;
        },
       },
   });
```

So here I am passing in the value in (`action.payload` is the value being passed in). When this action is dispatched, I want to remove just the word that is passed in from the features array. I hope this is clearer now.

This doesn't work for some reason and I am unable to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated please, thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't really reflect your state. What is `state.traits`? Where is the user `values` property? Are you trying to remove the whole user if "Short" is found in the `features` array, or just that word? Also, that's not an action. That's a reducer, and should return state from the function.

Comment: Hey @Andy, just edited it. Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: What's in action.payload and removedUsers? Can you put console.log or debugger?

Comment: Thanks @Andy! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't match your state structure. Replace `traits` with `users`, and `values` with `features`.
2. It looks like that's a part of a reducer, not an action (which is an object, not a function).
3. You should be returning a new state from the reducer.
4. Given your update the function should be called `removeFeature`.

So, I've corrected a few bits of your code based on what I remember from Redux. Note: contrived example.

```js
// State
const state={users:[{name:"joe",features:["Mean","Short"]},{name:"bolu",features:["Tall"]},{name:"cam",features:["Bearded","Short"]}]};

// The reducer accepts a state, and an action
function reducer(state, action) {

  // We destructure the type, and payload, from the action object
  const { type, payload } = action;

  // Depending on the type...
  switch (type) {

    case 'removeFeature': {
      
      // `map` over the users (we return a new state array)
      return state.users.map(user => {
        
        // `filter` out the feature elements
        // that match the payload
        const updatedFeatures = user.features.filter(feature => {
          return feature !== payload;
        });
        
        // Return a new updated object
        return { ...user, features: updatedFeatures };
      
      });
    
    }

    default: return state;

  }

}

const updatedState = reducer(state, {
  type: 'removeFeature',
  payload: 'Short'
});

console.log(updatedState);
```